# Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back

Tags: objective-c, pointers, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to pass pointer to pointer to a method, but apparently ARC has some issues with how I'm doing it. Here the two methods:

```
+ (NSString *)personPropertyNameForIndex:(kSHLPersonDetailsTableRowIndex)index 
{
    static NSArray *propertyNames = nil;

    (nil == propertyNames) ? 
        [self SHL_initPersonPropertyNamesWithArray:&propertyNames] : NULL;
}

+ (void)SHL_initPersonPropertyNamesWithArray:(NSArray **)theArray
{
    *theArray = [[NSArray alloc] 
                 initWithObjects:@"name", @"email", @"birthdate", @"phone", nil];
}
```

I receive the following error:

> Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back

On the line which the following command appears:

```
[self SHL_initPersonPropertyNamesWithArray:&propertyNames] : NULL;
```

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814718/handling-pointer-to-pointer-ownership-issues-in-arc?answertab=active#tab-top] as well, this will clarify most of doubts

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The __strong storage qualifier is needed for this case.

```
+ (void)SHL_initPersonPropertyNamesWithArray:(NSArray * __strong *)theArray
```

However, this code doesn't follow the [Basic Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

> You own any object you create
>
> You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

For what reason do you want to do this?

Comment: Well, instead of using a conditional IF every time this method is called, I use a ternary operation followed by an initialization function, but maybe it's better I'll stick with what familiar in the Objective-C world rather than C.