# Objective-C: Correct way to pass a property's reference into a method call

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa

If I have a property like this:

```
@property(strong, readwrite, nonatomic) NSDate* aProperty;
```

and I want to pass the reference into another method, are these correct:

```
if([AnotherClass aMethod:&(self.aProperty)]) { ...
if([AnotherClass aMethod:&self.aProperty]) { ...
```

Comment: Actually, Xcode throws an error "Address of property express required"

Comment: Actually, it's not Xcode but the compiler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Considering your example:

```
if ([AnotherClass aMethod:&(self.aProperty)]) { ...
```

This obviously won't work because the dot notation is, effectively, using the getter accessor method. It's equivalent to:

```
if ([AnotherClass aMethod:&[self aProperty]]) { ...
```

You can easily imagine why the compiler is a little confused about this notation. The logical alternative would be to reference the ivar. Thus, (assuming you're using the underscore convention for the property's ivar) it might look like:

```
if ([AnotherClass aMethod:&_aProperty]) { ...
```

But that has all sorts of issues (bypassing setter, having issues about `aMethod` needing `__strong` attribute to override the default `__autoreleasing` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422679/1271826), etc.).

So, probably best, just have a local variable that receives the update, and then invoke the property's setter subsequent to that:

```
NSDate *date;
if ([AnotherClass aMethod:&date]) { ...

self.aProperty = date;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use KeyValue coding.

just send name of a property as NSString

```
- (void) method:(NSString*)propertyName
{
  [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:propertyName];
}
```

also a property is just to methods (set and get), so you can pass a selector

```
SEL selector = @selector(setProperty:);

- (void) method:(SEL)selector target:(id)target
{
  [target performSelector:selector withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
}
```

i prefer to use key value coding.

Comment: Your approach is preferable since the first class can log in the setter when it's getting set and to what value. In @Rob s solution the original class never knows if that variable is getting changed behind its back.

Comment: Both appear to be much better answers than the others here.

Answer (score 2):

```
aProperty
```

is already a pointer to the NSDate object, so you just pass the pointer value along for 'call by reference'.

As the item is declared as a pointer, you can pass the reference using,

```
if([AnotherClass aMethod:aProperty]) { ...
```

where the prototype for aMethod is...

```
- (BOOL) aMethod:(NSDate *) aParameter;
```

(the above is true unless you really do want to pass a pointer to the property itself - to modify the pointer to the property itself, in which case I would question your design)

Comment: This is not really what/where the problem is. I still agree with you on OP's design being fundamentally flawed, but the problem is that he wants another method to modify a variable, which is missing one level of indirection in your answer.