# Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.2, autorelease

I'm trying to make app with xcode 4.2 and i'm really confused whay happen this.
Could someone help me an explain me why have error in lines when appear &error

Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back

[RootViewController.h](http://pastie.org/2938106)

[RootViewController.m](http://pastie.org/2938098)

Comment: The solution... In .h --> NSError *__autoreleasing * error; In.m --> [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:error];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would have been easier to diagnose the error without having to guess at the line number on which it occurs, but I **think** the issue is your use of the error instance variable to pass as the error here:

```
30    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &error];
```

also here

```
49    [fm removeItemAtPath:[recordedTmpFile path] error:&error];
```

The reason is that, if an error occcurs, in `setCategory:error:` the existing value of `error` will be overwritten without being released and is thus a potential leak.

Comment: the lines with error are:

30 [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &error];

32 [audioSession setActive:YES error: &error];

49 [fm removeItemAtPath:[recordedTmpFile path] error:&error];

108 recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:&error];

142 AVAudioPlayer * avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile error:&error];

Comment: The solution... 
In .h --> NSError *__autoreleasing * error;
In.m --> [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:error];

Comment: @Javi: that's not the solution.  Your instance variable will be nil and so not used.  If that's what you want, just pass `nil` directly to the methods.

Comment: Here is correct answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963538/error-passing-address-of-non-local-object-to-autoreleasing-parameter-for-writ