# [NSError retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nserror

I am using a third party library and make a call to one of its functions like this.

```
NSError* error = nil;
self.updatedDocument.bookmarkParser.bookmarks = newBookmarks;
//save the document
[self.updatedDocument.bookmarkParser saveBookmarksWithError:&error];
[self.updatedDocument saveAnnotationsWithError:&error];
```

The third party apis .h file looks like this.

```
/// Saves the bookmark into a plist file at bookmarkPath.
/// @note Saving is done async.
- (BOOL)saveBookmarksWithError:(NSError *__autoreleasing*)error;
```

I am not sure if I am correctly using this NSError pointer as I am not sure what *__autoreleasing does. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `__autoreleasing*` release the objects on returning. I am not sure but i think your assumption about using a released object in second method call is correct. Check the Colin's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502116/use-of-autoreleasing-in-code-snippet-example). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862023/in-which-situations-do-we-need-to-write-the-autoreleasing-ownership-qualifier) thread also address this concept.

Answer (score 0):

__autoreleasing means the library is ARC enabled and you don't need to release the NSError returned by the saveBookmarksWithError method. You can pass a nil value to this method if don't want to handle the error condition. Otherwise you can pass a NSError pointer as you given in the sample code and display to user or write to log.

Comment: Just after this I call a different method but using the same error , can this be causing the crash..? As this was already released and the second method tries to retain it..?

Comment: If you are using ARC then NSError will not be released when pass to another method. Can you please share your code here.

Comment: I have shared it in the question.