# ios __weak and __autoreleasing

Tags: ios, pass-by-reference, weak, hidden-variables

I got some questions after reading the answer to this thread [Handling Pointer-to-Pointer Ownership Issues in ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814718/handling-pointer-to-pointer-ownership-issues-in-arc);

For demo 1, when a reference to a 'strong' attributed variable is passed, a hidden(__autoreleasing) variable is implicitly created and the object doesn't get retained.
However for demo 4, when a reference to a 'weak' attributed variable is passed, the object does get retained once.

So my question is quite simple as just my curiosity, why only the hidden variable created from '__weak' gets the object retain+1? Is this pattern designed for any special concerns?

Hoping I explain my question clearly, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like an interesting question, but you should copy the relevant code and paste it directly into your text so people can understand without jumping between pages.

Comment: I believe weak references are retained/autoreleased when they are accessed--this prevents them from zeroing part way through a method using a weak reference.

Comment: @nevan king: i tried to copy and paste here, but the demo snippets there are long and messed up as well as with many comments. thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> a hidden(__autoreleasing) variable is implicitly created and the
>   object doesn't get retained

This is not true. `__autoreleasing` is something that is retained and autoreleased.