# Managing the memory for an object passed in to an in-out argument

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-coding

I wonder how memory management must be done for method parameters that are used to pass values into the method and (optionally) return updated values from the method.

For example, the `-validate<Key>:error:` method in KVC has a `(id *)ioValue` parameter that can be updated by the method. You can return an autoreleased object but what should you do with the input object when updating? Are there any conventions for this case?

Comment: If you are updating an object, rather than creating one, then there are no memory management issues are there?  The object has been allocated and you are modifying one of its properties.

Comment: I am thinking about different scenario when you completely replace the input object. Just updating the input object would mean that your object is passed as _in_ argument not as _in-out_ . Take a look at -validate<Key>:error: or validateValue:forKey:error: method description of NSKeyValueCoding protocol.

Comment: @yurish - see this question for a detailed look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814718/handling-pointer-to-pointer-ownership-issues-in-arc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything particularly complex about replacing an object reference with a new object, just as taking a `nil` reference and making it valid when an object is first created.

If you are using ARC then the compiler will realise that the old reference has been replaced, just like it would in any other situation.  If using MRR then you are required to observe the normal `retain`/`release` conventions in order to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: I had to understand this myself :) So you just must be extra careful when calling such method and assume that the argument you passed in may be changed.