# Issues with double pointers in ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have some variables, which cache some data from a webservice.

To make my code more dynamic, I want to return a double pointer to the cache-variable.
So it's a double pointer. I have some issues doing this with ARC.

Here's what I got:

---

```
- (id *)pointerToSectionCacheProperty:(SomeSection)section {
    switch (section) {
        case Section1:
        {
            return &_section1Cache;
        }
            break;
        case Section2:
        {
            return &_section2Cache;
        }
            break;
        case Section3:
        {
            return &_section3Cache;
        }
            break;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

---

ARC gives me the following error:

```
Returning 'NSArray *__strong *' from a function with result type '__autoreleasing id *' changes retain/release properties of pointer
```

---

Is this the wrong approach?

If so, what is the right approach?

Comment: What purpose does the double pointer serve? ARC is simply confused, function results are autorelease by default, what does your NSArray * have as its declarations?

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits It's simply `strong`variable

Comment: I believe the correct decl would be (strong NSArray **) since the caller will effectively have to manage that object on their own if they change the value.

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits You were very close :) Added the solution

Comment: Hah I really should learn ARC. You should also mark it as answered.

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits That's only possible in 2 days...

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814718/handling-pointer-to-pointer-ownership-issues-in-arc/8829294#8829294) - it is not exactly the same situation, as it is directed at passing pointers to pointers *into* methods and not receiving them *from* methods, but the same principles apply. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

---

Got it working like this:

---

```
- (NSArray *__strong *)pointerToSectionCacheProperty:(SomeSection)section {
    switch (section) {
        case Section1:
        {
            return &_section1Cache;
        }
            break;
        case Section2:
        {
            return &_section2Cache;
        }
            break;
        case Section3:
        {
            return &_section3Cache;
        }
            break;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

---

As a sidenote, `- (id __strong *)...` will work just as well.