# Why does ARC only sometimes retain a __block out pointer?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

1) Why does this retain its `__block` var:

```
{
    void (^blockWithOutPointer)(NSObject * __autoreleasing *) = ^(NSObject * __autoreleasing * outPointer) {
        *outPointer = [NSObject new];
    };

    NSObject * __block blockVar1;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                                 (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   ^{
                       NSLog(@"blockVar1: %@",
                             blockVar1);
                       // prints non-nil. WHY????
                   });
    blockWithOutPointer(&blockVar1);
}
```

2) But this doesn't?

```
void (^blockWithOutPointerThatDispatchesLater)(NSObject * __autoreleasing *,
                                               dispatch_block_t) = ^(NSObject * __autoreleasing * outPointer,
                                                                     dispatch_block_t block) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                                 (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   block);
    *outPointer = [NSObject new];
};

{
    NSObject * __block blockVar2;
    blockWithOutPointerThatDispatchesLater(&blockVar2,
                                           ^{
                                               NSLog(@"blockVar2: %@",
                                                     blockVar2);
                                           });
    // prints nil, which is expected.
}
```

3) If I instead use an `__autoreleasing` variable as my out pointer destination, and then assign that variable to my `__block` pointer, everything works fine.

```
{
    NSObject * __autoreleasing autoreleasingVar;
    NSObject * __block blockVar3;
    blockWithOutPointerThatDispatchesLater(&autoreleasingVar,
                                           ^{
                                               NSLog(@"blockVar3: %@",
                                                     blockVar3);
                                           });
    blockVar3 = autoreleasingVar;
    // prints non-nil, which is expected.
}
```

I've read [CRD's answer about ARC pointer-to-pointer issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8829294/9636), it makes sense that #2 would print nil because ARC assumes that `blockVar2` is `__autoreleasing`, and doesn't retain its value. Thus, in #3, when we assign `autoreleasingVar` to `blockVar3`, ARC properly retains the value. However, there is no such assignment for #1. Why does #1 retain its value?

Even more amazingly, #1 is unaffected if I wrap the out-pointer assignment in an `@autoreleasepool`:

```
{
    void (^blockWithOutPointer)(NSObject * __autoreleasing *) = ^(NSObject * __autoreleasing * outPointer) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            *outPointer = [NSObject new];
        }
    };

    NSObject * __block blockVar1;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                                 (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   ^{
                       NSLog(@"blockVar1: %@",
                             blockVar1);
                       // still prints non-nil. WHY???
                   });
    blockWithOutPointer(&blockVar1);
}
```

Whereas #3 crashes, as expected since the `@autoreleasepool` released the out-pointer's object, and I guess ARC doesn't set `__autoreleasing` variables to `nil`.

```
void (^blockWithOutPointerThatDispatchesLater)(NSObject * __autoreleasing *,
                                               dispatch_block_t) = ^(NSObject * __autoreleasing * outPointer,
                                                                     dispatch_block_t block) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                                 (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   block);
    @autoreleasepool {
        *outPointer = [NSObject new];
    }
};

{
    NSObject * __autoreleasing autoreleasingVar;
    NSObject * __block blockVar3;
    blockWithOutPointerThatDispatchesLater(&autoreleasingVar,
                                           ^{
                                               NSLog(@"blockVar3: %@",
                                                     blockVar3);
                                               // crashes on the NSLog!
                                           });
    blockVar3 = autoreleasingVar;
}
```

I filed a [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/25489844) about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have discovered a "feature" of the block implementation and (at least for cases 1 & 2, I haven't checked further) it is nothing to do with `__autoreleasing` *per se*.

First let's look at your case 1. You seem surprised this prints a non-nil value. It works exactly as expected:

1. `blockWithOutPointer(&blockVar1);` executes, assigning a value to `blockVar1`; then
2. the block `^{ NSLog(@"blockVar1: %@", blockVar1); }` is executed by GCD and the stored by (1) is printed.

(Note: You can removed the `__autoreleasing` qualifiers and it will work the same as this is the inferred mode for pass-by-writeback parameters.)

Now your case 2. This is where you hit the "feature":

1. In Objective-C objects are heap allocated; and
2. Objective-C blocks are objects; so
3. Ergo blocks are heap allocated...
4. Except when they are not...

As an *optimisation* the block specification allows blocks and their captured `__block` variables to be stack allocated and only moved onto the heap when their lifetime needs to be longer than the stack frame are in.

As an *optimisation* it should (a) be essentially invisible to the programmer - apart from any perf benefit and (b) not change the semantics in anyway. However Apple decided to initially introduce it as a "programmer assisted optimisation" and have then slowly improved matters.

The behaviour of your case 2 is all down to when the block and `__block` variable get copied onto the heap. Let's look at the code:

```
NSObject * __block blockVar2;
```

This declares `blockVar2` to have `__block` storage duration, which allows a block to alter the value of this locally declared variable. At this point the compiler does not know whether a block may access it, in which case `blockVar2` will need to be on the heap, or whether it won't, in which case it may be on the stack.

The compiler decides it prefers the stack and allocates `blockVar2` there.

```
blockWithOutPointerThatDispatchesLater(&blockVar2,
```

Now the compiler needs to pass the address of `blockVar2` as the first argument, the variable is currently on the stack, and the compiler emits code to calculate its address. That address is *on the stack*.

```
                                       ^{
                                           NSLog(@"blockVar2: %@",
                                                 blockVar2);
                                       });
```

Now the compiler gets to the second argument. It sees the block, that the block accesses `blockVar2`, and that `blockVar2` is qualified by `__block` so it must capture the *variable* itself and **not** the variables value.

The compiler decides the block should go on the heap. For this to work it needs to migrate `blockVar2` onto the heap, so it does that along with its current value `nil`...

> **Oops!**
>
> The first argument is the address of the original `blockVar2` on the stack, while the second argument is a block which in turn references the cloned `blockVar2` on the heap.

When the code is executed `blockWithOutPointerThatDispatchesLater()` allocates an object and stores its address in the *stack* `blockVar2`; then GCD executes the delayed block which prints of the value of the *heap* `blockVar2`, which is `nil`.

**A “Fix”**

Just change your code to:

```
NSObject * __block blockVar2;
dispatch_block_t afterBlock = ^{
     NSLog(@"blockVar2: %@", blockVar2);
};
blockWithOutPointerThatDispatchesLater(&blockVar2, afterBlock);
```

i.e. pre-calculate the second argument expression. Now the compiler sees the block before it sees `&blockVar2`, moves the block and `blockVar2` to the heap, and the value generated for `&blockVar2` is the address of the *heap* version of `blockVar2`.

> **Expanded Conclusion: Bug or Feature?**

The original answer simply stated this is clearly a bug, not a feature, and suggest you file a bug report, noting it's been reported before but another report won't harm.

However that might be a little unfair, yes it is a *bug*, the question is what the bug actually is. Consider:

- In (Objective-)C variables, allocated on the stack or statically, and allocated dynamic memory blocks do not move during their lifetime.
- Compiler optimisations in general should not alter the meaning or correctness of a program.

Apple has implemented a compiler optimisation – storing blocks and captured `__block` variables on the stack – in a way which *can* move `__block` attributed variables during their lifetime and in doing so the meaning and correctness of a program can be altered.

The result is a simple re-ordering of program statements in a way which should not alter program meaning or correctness in fact does. **This is bad!**

Given the history of the optimisation, as implemented by Apple, which by-design relied on programmer assistance (though it has since been made more automatic) for its correctness this could simply be seen as another “feature” of the chosen implementation.

> **Recommendation**

Never, ever, apply the address-of (`&`) operator to a variable with `__block` storage duration. If *may* work if you do, but it just as easily may not.

If you need to use a `__block` variable as a pass-by-writeback argument then copy it to a local temporary first, make the call, and finally copy it back again.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a misconception in 1):

If a variable will be imported into a block, which is marked with `__block` the compiler generates a helper struct containing various fields and the variable corresponding to the given source. That is, there's no pointer `blockVar1`, instead there's a whole struct instead.

If a block imports this variable and needs to be copied (for example, when asynchronously submitted) it also "moves" this helper struct onto the heap before "moving" the block itself onto the heap.

This statement

```
NSObject * __block blockVar1;
```

will initialise the helper struct which embeds the actual variable and initialises it to `nil`. The corresponding address of the variable points into the stack.

When the compiler parses this statement:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                             (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
               dispatch_get_main_queue(),
               ^{
                   NSLog(@"blockVar1: %@",
                         blockVar1);
                   // prints non-nil. WHY????
               });
```

The compiler generates code for the compound statement, specifically it creates a struct representing the block which initially exists on the stack, too. Since this block requires to be moved to the heap before executing `dispatch_async`, it also moves the helper struct onto the heap in subsequently generated code.

Additionally, since the imported variable is a `NSObject` pointer, it also assigns function pointers (located in the helper struct) which "keep" and "dispose" the object, which will be called when the helper struct is "moved" to the heap, respectively when it is destroyed.

When you finally execute this statement

```
blockWithOutPointer(&blockVar1);
```

the address of the variable has already been changed: the variable is now located on the heap (since the helper struct has been "moved" to the heap") and exists as long as the block.

---

Now, to the point where you declare (and define) the following block:

```
void (^blockWithOutPointer)(NSObject * __autoreleasing *)
```

What causes gripes here is the `__autoreleasing` modifier, specifically [Storage duration of __autoreleasing objects](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id26):

That is, `__autoreleasing` can only be applied to variables with *automatic storage duration*.

**Edit:**

<s>This would assume that the given variable is on the stack. However, it is located on the heap. Thus, your program is illformed and the behaviour is undefined.</s>

Regarding the `__autoreleasing` storage qualifier, the code sample 1) is correct (the `_autoreleasing` storage qualifier refers to a temporary that is created when passing the variable as a parameter, see comments below).

What I've said previously above should be correct, and what the user is experiencing is thus expected.

For further reference see: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html

*However*:

There's still a subtle *potential* issue with a "data race": the statement

```
blockWithOutPointer(&blockVar1);
```

will modify a pointer variable which is located on the heap, while executing on the *current thread*. Later, on the *main thread* the same variable will be read. Unless *current thread*  equals *main thread*, this exhibits a classic data race.

While this is not the question and no a complete answer - it shows, how quickly such code becomes more complex than desired and I would recommend to strive for simpler, comprehensible code.

**End Edit**

---

I haven't analysed the other code samples

<s>- but at the first glance it seems, using `__autoreleasing` leads also to an illformed program.</s>

Comment: Sorry, but I think your analysis is wrong. The problem stems from the overloading of the term *object*. Check section 4 of the reference Clang doc and you'll find "This section describes the behavior of *objects* of retainable object pointer type; that is, locations in memory which store retainable object pointers.", i.e. object is being used for *variable*, and this is not uncommon in language descriptions. Ownership qualification is a property of variable declarations, not of the Objective-C objects which the pointers in those variable reference. The `__autoreleasing` ownership qualifier...

Comment: is only allowed on variables of automatic storage duration - and that covers parameter variables such as that of `blockWithOutPointer`. So the OP's program is not ill-formed for this reason. I haven't analysed the code further myself (at least not yet, we'll see).

Comment: @CRD Thanks for your input on this subject. But let me emphasise, that at the time this statement `blockWithOutPointer(&blockVar1); ` is executed, the _pointer_ (aka _variable_) to the Objective-C object  resides on the heap.This is due to the fact, that the helper struct (which embeds the actual _variable_) has been "moved" to the heap as a consequence of moving the block on the heap. Since the access to the variable is actual _indirect_ (due to being defined in a _struct_) and because the parameter is the _address_ of the variable, complicates the matter. So, I'll have to rethink this issue.

Comment: @CRD Please see also: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html#access-to-block-variables-from-within-its-lexical-scope

Comment: @CRD Since `__autoreleasing` is marked on a _function parameter_, and parameters are always on the stack - that is, they reside in automatic storage - _could_ mean, that using `__autoreleasing` for parameters is always legal? This might be true, but we have a _pointer_ to it: a `NSObject * __autoreleasing *` aka `"pointer to (__autoreleasing variable)"`. So, IMHO, _variable_ resides not in automatic storage.

Comment: What matters is not where `blockVar1` resides but that it is (implicitly) strong and it is being passed as a parameter of type "pointer to autoreleasing reference to an object" - this is the condition for pass-by-writeback. Behind the scenes the compiler will use a temporary autoreleasing local and pass its address.

Comment: @CRD So,  `__autorelease` refers to the _temporary_. So, the object created via `*outPointer = [NSObject new];` is seen outside as an autoreleased object. Similar like a method that returns a newly created object and passes ownership to the caller. Then it is legal code, but IMHO - __autoreleasing could also be omitted - and at least 1) is correct, and what the OP is experiencing is expected.